# PlayOnLinux cannot find Wine (though it is installed with POL)

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Really strange, i use PlayOnLinux (POL) to install *Wine 1.7.9*, i rebooted my PC and when i try to open POL it says it can't find Wine, although it's listed under *installed Wine versions*. What do?

Also, my terminal doesn't recognize the `wine` command. Faulty install? If so, How do i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The original poster, [PDiracDelta](https://askubuntu.com/users/231008/pdiracdelta), provided their solution [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398964/playonlinux-cannot-find-wine-though-it-is-installed-with-pol/622585#comment512975_399024):

> Actually, I've found the solution: apparently it takes several seconds to populate the list of available Wine versions, with no warning that POL is still populating the list. I seem to have closed it too early each time. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Just install Wine manually using [WineHQ's Installation Guide](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) and then try running PlayOnLinux afterwards.

Otherwise, you may need to give PoL time to populate the Wine list, as explained by the first comment belonging to this answer.

Comment: Actually, I've found the solution: apparently it takes several seconds to populate the list of available Wine versions, with no warning that POL is still populating the list. I seem to have closed it too early each time. But thanks anyway!